# If $20x=\pi$, what is $\frac{\cos 4x - \cos 8x}{\cos 4x\cdot \cos 8x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $20x=\pi$,
what is $$\frac{\cos 4x - \cos 8x}{\cos 4x\cdot \cos 8x}?$$

I've tried using the [factor formula](http://www.trigonometry-help.net/trig-formulas.php) on the numerator but I haven't managed to get anywhere with it...

This is a multiple choice question with options $4$, $2$, $1$, $-1$, and $-2$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\\ 20x=\pi \\ 10x=\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } \\ \frac { \cos { \left( 10x-6x \right) -\cos { \left( 10x-2x \right)  }  }  }{ \cos { \left( 10x-6x \right) \cos { \left( 10x-2x \right)  }  }  } =\frac { \sin { \left( 6x \right) -\sin { \left( 2x \right)  }  }  }{ \sin { \left( 6x \right) \sin { \left( 2x \right)  }  }  } =\frac { 2\sin { \left( 2x \right) \cos { \left( 4x \right)  }  }  }{ \sin { \left( 6x \right) \sin { \left( 2x \right)  }  }  } =2\frac { \cos { \left( 4x \right)  }  }{ \sin { \left( 6x \right)  }  } =2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $4x=\pi-16x$, so $\cos4x=\cos(\pi-16x)=-\cos16x$. By the [sum-to-product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities),
$$
\cos16x+\cos8x=2\cos12x\cos4x
$$
and we have a first simplification:
$$
\frac{\cos 4x - \cos 8x}{\cos 4x\cdot \cos 8x}=
-\frac{2\cos12x}{\cos8x}
$$
Now $12x=\pi-8x$, so $\cos12x=-\cos8x$

Answer (score 0):

If for some integer $n,5y=(2n+1)\pi,$

$$\cos3y=\cos\{(2n+1)\pi-2y\}=-\cos2y$$

$$-\cos2y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y=2\cos y(1+\cos2y)-3\cos y$$

$$\iff\cos y-\cos2y=2\cos y\cos2y$$

$$\iff\dfrac{\cos y-\cos2y}{\cos y\cos2y}=2$$

Here $y=4x,n=?$